# submit number of files using ajax

Tags: php, jquery

I have form with text fields and files.

I'm trying to submit the form and upload the files with ajax. the problem is when I print `(var_dump ($_POST['file']);)` the files's data in the ajax file (attractions-control.php) i'm getting nothing:

```
array (size=2)
  0 => string '' (length=0)
  1 => string '' (length=0)
```

How can i fix that?

JS PART

```
e.preventDefault();

var formData = $(this).closest('form').serializeArray();
formData.push({name: 'act', value: 'edit'});        


var file_data = $(this).parents("form").find('.multi').prop('files');   



var filesArray = $(this).parents("form").find('.multi');
jQuery.each(filesArray, function(i, fileArray) 
{
    var files = fileArray.files;
    var file;
    formData.push({name: 'file[]', value: file});   
});



$.ajax ({
  type: 'POST',
  url: 'ajax/attractions-control.php',
  data: formData,
  dataType    : 'json',
  async: false,
  code        : true
}).done(function(data) 
{
}
```

HTML PART

```
<form id="attrac-form-<?PHP echo $mainIndex['id'] ?>" action="#"  method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="attrac-form">

      <input type="text" name="title" >

      <input type="file" name="file[]" class="multi">

      <input type="file" name="file[]" class="multi">

      <input type="file" name="file[]" class="multi">

      <input class="attrac-submit" value="SEND" type="submit" >

</form>
```

Comment: try to use the FormData() object like `new FormData($('form')[0])`, you'll have all inside and your files will be usable with $_FILES

Comment: i think it will be good, but i'm not sure how to do it. can you please show me example ? @MacBooc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is working for me

Javascript:

```
var form = $(this).closest('form')[0]; // derived from your code

// remove empty file inputs from form otherwise some browsers throw error 
for (i = 0; i < form.elements.length; i++) {
  if (form.elements[i].type == 'file') {
    if (form.elements[i].value == '') {
      form.elements[i].parentNode.removeChild(form.elements[i]);
    }
  }
}

var formData = new FormData(form);

$.ajax({
        url : "file.php",
        type: "POST",
        data : formData,
        dataType : "json",
        contentType: false,
        cache: false,
        processData:false
    })
.done(function(data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

PHP:

```
foreach ($_FILES as $key => $value) {
  //handle your files
}
```

Comment: If i want to add parameters to the POST, how can i do that?
in my code, above, i used `formData.push({name: 'act', value: 'edit'}); `

Comment: Yes I believe that is possible. Or you can add an hidden input with the value in the form

Answer (score 0):

Use the FormData object :

```
$.ajax ({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'ajax/attractions-control.php',
    data: new FormData($('form')[0]),
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    async: false
})
```

this will send you something in this structure :

```
-----------------------------951861112078
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="sdfer"

0
-----------------------------951861112078
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="sfd"; filename=""
Content-Type: application/octet-stream


-----------------------------951861112078
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="zre"

0
-----------------------------951861112078
```

that you can get by the $_FILES in PHP, and also all the form will be include so all input type text, for example will also be accessible using $_POST